# SortedOrder Enum for listbox control

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum containing the following (for example):

```
clmn=543, 
tclk=432,   , 
tolf=876, 
frol=654
```

I have to bind this enum keys to ItemsSource property of ListBox control in sorted order.
Enum should be sorted by value.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Code to Sort Enum:

```
   public static SortedList<int, string> GetEnumDataSource<T>()
    {
        Type myEnumType = typeof(T);
        SortedList<int, string> returnCollection = new SortedList<int, string>();
        try
        {
            if (myEnumType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
            {
                string[] enumNames = Enum.GetNames(myEnumType);
                int enumLength = enumNames.Length - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i <= enumLength; i++)
                {
                    returnCollection.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(myEnumType, enumNames[i])), enumNames[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {

            return null;
        }
        return returnCollection;
    }
```

'Code to bind the enum to drop down listbox:

```
public void BindBox()
{
    SortedList<int, string> phoneTypes = null;
    phoneTypes = GetEnumDataSource<PhoneNumberType>();

    if ((phoneTypes != null)) {
        dropdownctrl.DataSource = phoneTypes;
        dropdownctrl.DataValueField = "Key";
        dropdownctrl.DataTextField = "Value";
        dropdownctrl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: :Is it going to sort enum by defined values?

Comment: Yes, GetEnumDataSource function will sort the enum values and return to calling function BindBox().

Answer (score 0):

```
MemberInfo[] memberInfos = typeof(MyEnum)
                          .GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

mylistBox.ItemSource =  memberInfos.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gets values of MyEnum and sort them, hope it help you.

```
var values = typeof(MyEnum).GetEnumValues();
Array.Sort(values);
```